# Quick UL / LI Default child issue

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/b4fwQ/

Hi all.  The link above goes to a jsFiddle example of where i have got to thus far.  What i am trying to accomplish is that which ever `<li>` has the selected class on it will shows its child.  Now this is working as above, but once you start moving your mouse around the "selected" border needs to become white as you are now looking at a different page.

How can the css be changed?

thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current HTML markup I'm not sure this is possible with pure CSS. But a bit of jQuery can get the desired effect:

```
​$(function(){
    var selectedLi = $("#navigation ul#home-nav li.grey");
    $("#navigation ul#home-nav").hover(function(){
       selectedLi.removeClass("selected");
    }, function(){
       selectedLi.addClass("selected");   
    });
});​
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b4fwQ/1/

Comment: Very nice..Thanks for that..I assumed some jQuery would be required but could not mentally think how to..thanks alot!